# How to put a flex application in a PDF sidebar?

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flash

I want to embed a Flex application (i.e. a Flash SWF) into a PDF to run as a sidebar window.

Where can I find a good example of this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what a sidebar window is.

Comment: It's a separate pane (window) apart from the document itself. For example, the table of contents is in a sidebar.

Comment: Do you have an example handy of a PDF using a sidebar window for some other purpose?  I'd no idea modern PDFs might be able to do something as involved as embedding external applications within themselves.

Comment: I've seen some simple examples, but I want a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to embeed a Flash SWF application or Javascript application into a PDF file, you need to wrap it in a [Rich Media Annotation](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/category/acrobat/rich-media-annotations). There is another post that you may find helpful: [Controlling the position of a floating Rich Media Annotation](http://acrobatninja.blogspot.ca/2011/03/controlling-position-of-floating-rich.html).

Answer (score 0):

in case if you meant windows sidebar:

to display your flex application as sidebar window you just need to pack it's files into *.gadget file, it should be zip archive with all flex app files + gadget.xml inside.

you can download any gadget from microsoft website
for example: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/E/3/5E316832-F284-42FD-A793-A84FCFA0E299/Google_Gadget_EN.gadget

rename .gadget file to .zip file, extract archive and check all files inside

Comment: No, sorry. I mean put a JavaScript or Flex application into a PDF itself.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the issue, **alivepdf**

http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Other references

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-flash-swf.htm

http://www.adobe.com/designcenter-archive/tutorials/flashpdf/

But the below link is avaialble only for **AIR**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLPDFCapability.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Comment: No, I want to put a Flex application into a PDF, not create a PDF from a Flex application